# How to set OpenCV Mat as Tensorflow Lite input and output?

Tags: c++, opencv, tensorflow, objective-c++, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to use GPU Delegate in Tensorflow Lite on iOS. My model has inputs and outputs as OpenCV BGR image ([258, 540, 3]). How can I set inputs and outputs in C++ tensorflow lite interpreter? I tried to use this code

```
int input = interpreter->inputs()[0];
float* out = interpreter->typed_tensor<float>(input);
NSData* slicedData = [self inputDataFromCvMat:slicedImage];
uint8_t* in = (uint8_t*) slicedData.bytes; 
ProcessInputWithFloatModel(in, out, WIDTH, HEIGHT, CHANNELS);
```

```
void ProcessInputWithFloatModel(uint8_t* input, float* buffer, int image_width, int image_height, int image_channels) {
  for (int y = 0; y < wanted_input_height; ++y) {
    float* out_row = buffer + (y * wanted_input_width * wanted_input_channels);
    for (int x = 0; x < wanted_input_width; ++x) {
      const int in_x = (y * image_width) / wanted_input_width;
      const int in_y = (x * image_height) / wanted_input_height;
      uint8_t* input_pixel =
      input + (in_y * image_width * image_channels) + (in_x * image_channels);
      float* out_pixel = out_row + (x * wanted_input_channels);
      for (int c = 0; c < wanted_input_channels; ++c) {
        out_pixel[c] = (input_pixel[c] - input_mean) / input_std;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
- (NSData *)inputDataFromCvMat:(Mat)image {
  NSMutableData *inputData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
  for (int row = 0; row < HEIGHT + 10; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < WIDTH + 10; col++) {
      Vec3b intensity = image.at<Vec3b>(row, col);
      int blue = intensity.val[0];
      int green = intensity.val[1];
      int red = intensity.val[2];
      // we need to put pixel values in BGR (model was trained with opencv)
      [inputData appendBytes:&blue length:sizeof(blue)];
      [inputData appendBytes:&green length:sizeof(green)];
      [inputData appendBytes:&red length:sizeof(red)];
    }
  }
  return inputData;
}
```

but I don't know what is wrong

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some research, I managed to get it working

```
const int wanted_input_width = 258;
const int wanted_input_height = 540;
const int wanted_input_channels = 3;

Mat image = ...

// write to input
int input = interpreter->inputs()[0];
float* out = interpreter->typed_tensor<float>(input);
uint8_t* in = image.ptr<uint8_t>(0);
ProcessInputWithFloatModel(in, out);
// run interpreter
if (interpreter->Invoke() != kTfLiteOk) {
   LOG(FATAL) << "Failed to invoke!";
}
// get output      
int output_idx = interpreter->outputs()[0];
float* output = interpreter->typed_output_tensor<float>(output_idx);
Mat outputMat = ProcessOutputWithFloatModel(output);
```

```
/// Preprocess the input image and feed the TFLite interpreter buffer for a float model.
void ProcessInputWithFloatModel(uint8_t* input, float* buffer) {
  for (int y = 0; y < wanted_input_height; ++y) {
    float* out_row = buffer + (y * wanted_input_width * wanted_input_channels);
    for (int x = 0; x < wanted_input_width; ++x) {
      uint8_t* input_pixel = input + (y * wanted_input_width * wanted_input_channels) + (x * wanted_input_channels);
      float* out_pixel = out_row + (x * wanted_input_channels);
      for (int c = 0; c < wanted_input_channels; ++c) {
        out_pixel[c] = input_pixel[c] / 255.0f;
      }
    }
  }
}

Mat ProcessOutputWithFloatModel(float* input) {
  cv::Mat image = cv::Mat::zeros(wanted_input_height, wanted_input_width, CV_8UC3);
  for (int y = 0; y < wanted_input_height; ++y) {
    for (int x = 0; x < wanted_input_width; ++x) {
      float* input_pixel = input + (y * wanted_input_width * wanted_input_channels) + (x * wanted_input_channels);
      cv::Vec3b & color = image.at<cv::Vec3b>(cv::Point(x, y));
      color[0] = (uchar) floor(input_pixel[0] * 255.0f);
      color[1] = (uchar) floor(input_pixel[1] * 255.0f);
      color[2] = (uchar) floor(input_pixel[2] * 255.0f);
    }
  }
  return image;
}
```